# throw vs throw new Error

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between throw and throw new Error, I'm a bit confused it seems an Error object is created with just the throw keyword, so why is the new Error used with throw? 
example

```
try{
   throw "something went wrong";//this works
}
catch(e){
 console.log(e);
 }


 try{
    throw new Error("something went wrong");//this also works but with    
                                             // longer syntax
 }
 catch(e){
      console.log(e);
 }
```

Comment: No, an Error instance is **not** implicitly created by `throw`. The "operand" for `throw` can be any value, and that's what will be available in the `catch` clause.